# GDB loads unfindable script on shell start

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu, gdb

On my computer when starting a shell in GDB it would give a very standard shell (looks like "bash-4.4$")- ignoring most of my environment variables. The real problem for me is I cannot adjust the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable because of this reason.

More posts on SO suggest to check .bashrc and .profile, I did that. I even created a new user and the problem persist. So some script is loaded by GDB changing my PS1 and unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, I have no idea which process. For some reason Root does not have this problem.

This works:

```
delruej@delxps:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=Hello
delruej@delxps:~$ bash
delruej@delxps:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Hello
```

However this does not:

```
delruej@delxps:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=Hello
delruej@delxps:~$ gdb
(gdb) shell
bash-4.4$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It should be some script loaded by every user, but not by root.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I purged GDB, removed /usr/share/gdb/, reinstalled and the problem was fixed.

Comment: The famous "reboot" non-solution. I guess we'll never know what the real problem was.

Answer (score 0):

> So some script is loaded by GDB changing my PS1 and unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

No. GDB just loads your `$SHELL`, and your `$SHELL` unsets these environment variables for some reason.

You should look at values of `$SHELL` and possibly `$ENV`.

Note that:

1. Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is generally a mistake; you should strive to build your programs such that they don't require it.
2. You *can* set any environment variable inside GDB (you don't have to inherit them from parent shell) with `(gdb) set env FOO bar`.

Comment: 1. Its a testing program, its not written by me;
2. gets unset everytime

So some script is loaded by GDB changing my PS1 and unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH -> I mean the shell is executing some script in another way than a regular shell, since a regular shell keeps LD_LIBRARY_PATH.